# If post exist then display new menu item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to be able to display a different menu item if a post exists in a certain page, but unsure of how to best call the controller method in a partial.

I have a career page and if there is a post within that page I would like to display 'NEW' next to the career item in my menu, if no post exist then I just want it to display 'Careers'.

_header located in views -> layouts

```
<% if Careers.exists?(:id) %>
 <li><%= link_to 'Careers NEW', careers_path %></li>
<% else %>
 <li><%= link_to 'Careers', careers_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<li><%= link_to "Careers #{(Career.present?)? 'NEW' : ''}", careers_path %></li>
```

Comment: Thanks Rony. This worked for me. 

<li><%= link_to "Careers #{(Career.exists?)? 'NEW' : ''}", careers_path %></li>